# Where to contribute pictures of election leaftlets?

Tags: images, elections, contributing-data

In most countries before elections, every citizen receives by mail an envelope containing paper leaflets printed by each political group, each describing its political program.

I think that these documents have a great historical value.
I have thought about uploading them to Wikimedia Commons, but I don't think they are compatible with CC-BY-SA-3.0. For instance [this category](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:French_presidential_election_%282007%29) does not contain any of these leaflets.

What is the most appropriate repository where I can upload such political leaftlets?
Preferably one platform for the whole world.

Answer (score 5):

Unlock Democracy runs a project called [Election Leaflets](http://www.electionleaflets.org/).

You can take photos, scan the leaflets, or even post them to their address.

They've got a good repository of leaflets.

Comment: That's only for the UK, right?

Comment: Yes - but you didn't say which country you're in :-)  You could contact them and see if they're interested in ones from across Europe.

Answer (score 4):

I was not able to find anyone collecting leaflets for Europe generally.

Here are some sites I did find.

- Ireland: http://irishelectionliterature.wordpress.com/ including [Irish candidates for European Parliament elections](http://irishelectionliterature.wordpress.com/index-of-electionsparty-literature/2014-european-elections-leaflets/)
- Australia: http://www.electionleaflets.org.au/ accepts public contributions
- Los Angeles: http://digital.library.ucla.edu/campaign/ accepts contributions from "candidates and other election organizations"

Comment: The UCLA one says "a century of Los Angelese elections", does it mean it is limited to Los Angeles? By the way, I can't find any way to contribute to it.

Comment: from the UCLA site: "Candidates or other election organizations who wish to contribute materials (either electronic or paper) to the Campaign Literature collection should contact the Campaign Literature Librarian." and  http://digital.library.ucla.edu/campaign/about.html there is complete information about the scope of the archive (yes, essentially Los Angeles)